# How to detect real click using mouse or using .click() on tag button , a?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to detect if some of my users really click on vote button or using `click(`) function. My vote button is in button tag or a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HTMLElement.click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) function triggers a `click` event. It does not trigger the `mousedown` or `mouseup` event. This is not to say that no one can trigger a `mousedown` or `mouseup` event, but if you want to exclude cases of javascript code triggering a `click` event, you can simply listen for the `mousedown` or `mouseup` events.

Here is an ES6 example.

```js
const demo1 = document.getElementById('demo1');
const demo2 = document.getElementById('demo2');
demo1.addEventListener('click', e => {
    demo2.click();
},  false);
demo2.addEventListener('mousedown', e => { 
    console.log('clicked');
},  false);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="demo1">Demo 1</a> <a href="#" id="demo2">Demo 2</a>
```

If you don't care about Internet Explorer or Safari (honestly, who does), you can use [`Event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

Here is another ES6 example.

```js
const demo1 = document.getElementById('demo1');
const demo2 = document.getElementById('demo2');
demo1.addEventListener('click', e => {
    demo2.click();
},  false);
demo2.addEventListener('click', e => { 
    console.log(['not trusted', 'trusted'][+e.isTrusted]);
},  false);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="demo1">Demo 1</a> <a href="#" id="demo2">Demo 2</a>
```

Comment: yes,this works, but i am curious, i think demo2.addEventListener can be override. i am wrong or right?

Comment: What do you mean by override?

Comment: as you define demo2.addEventListener();
what if user again define this demo2.addEventListener('click',e=>{console.log('trusted');} ); using browser console, then i am pretty sure second definition works. Is there any bulletproof way that i can detect if users legit click and don't use any javascript code. please let me know any article or blog post ?

Comment: Adding a new event listener won't override the existing event listener. Of course they can add a new one that doesn't have the checks and balances of the first. You could obfuscate the code to make it harder for the user to read, but as long as the code is client side, there is no bullet proof solution.